# Как написать функцию заполняющую массив числами Фибоначчи?

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Проблема возможно простая, но я честно не понимаю как ее решить. Нужно написать функцию voidfibArray(int *fib, int len) которая заполняет массив fib размерности len числами Фибоначчи. Я попытался написать программу на Си, которая выполняет данную задачу. Несмотря на то, что компилятор реагирует нормально и ошибок не выдает, на этапе ввода в консоль ничего не происходит.
Прикладываю свой код(не судите строго, в Си новичок):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fibArray(int *fib, int len){
if(len<2){
    return 1;
}
else{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    printf("fib[%d] = ", i);
        fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
        printf("%d\n", fib[i]);
    }
}
}
#define LEN 10
int main(){
int fib[LEN];
fibArray(fib,LEN);
printf("%d\n", fibArray(fib,LEN));
rerutn 0;
}
```

Comment: сделайте инициализацию первых двух чисел Фиббоначи перед циклом.

Comment: @xmikex, а первая ветка тебя не смущает?

Comment: ну вообще может он код ошибки вернул равный 1 - и у него функция выдает ошибку при len<2 - так как особого смысла массив из одного элемента.

Comment: хотя у него же функция void, так что вообще не должна ничего возвращать. Это точно ошибка значит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void fibArray(int *fib, int len)
{
    if (len > 0) fib[0] = 1;
    if (len > 1) fib[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < len; i++)
    {
        fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
        printf("fib[%d] = %d\n", i, fib[i]);
    }
}
```

Хотя выводить и считать в одной функции не очень хорошее решение.

Comment: Не `<2` и `<3`, а `>0` и `>1`.

Comment: некоторые начинают последовательность с нуля.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, мне уже стыдно...

Comment: @xmikex Тогда просто заменить `if (len > 0) fib[0] = 1;` на `if (len > 0) fib[0] = 0;`.

Comment: Спасибо!Не могли бы вы сказать как мне сделать так чтобы эта функция мне выводила результат какой-то?А то я написал в main то что вы видите но ничего не выводится

Comment: Что вы хотите выводить? `void`? а при расчете все выводится - https://ideone.com/HXtC9E